# Access b2world from child class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d

I'm trying to place an object (Object.as) on stage and have it reference the (Main.as) _world:b2world. How could I accomplish this?

From Main.as (Document class)

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public var World:b2World;
}
```

How do I access the variable World from an object that's been added to the stage with it's own class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `World` to the Object you create. You can do it by setting it directly to a property or passing it to Objects constructor.

```
public class YourObject
{
    private var world:b2World;

    public function YourObject(world:b2World):void
    {
        this.world = world; // store a reference to world, now you can use `world` in this class
    }
}
```

Now from Main.as when you create an object and you can pass the world to the constructor.

```
public class Main extends MovieClip 
{

    public var World:b2World;
    public function test():void
    {
        var obj:YourObject = new YourObject(World);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I've actually done with other objects that were generated through code, but I wanted to place these objects on the stage in Flash. How would I do that?

Comment: If you are doing it in Flash then you need to make the `world` public in `YourObject` and set it in your code. Since you can't pass constructor parameters if you add stuff to the stage.

Comment: Well I have the `World` setup in the Main class. When I place the MovieClip on the stage, how does it look at Main's `World`? I've been trying to figure that one out. It's set to public but still comes up as null.

Comment: you would have to set the public world with the one from Main. Like `yourObject.world = World`